# How to resolve cloudflare not displaying my website on my phone

Tags: caching, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudflare, amazon-elb

I keep having this error when I try to access my website that is hosted on aws and using cloudflare CDN.

But the surprising thing is that it is loading correctly on another person's phone.

What can be the issue and how can I resolve it?

[Cloudflare error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo4C7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This error specified a connection error between Cloudflare and your Origin server.

There are a couple ways this could be occurring on your device but not another's -

1. If you recently added Cloudflare, the DNS may still be resolving to your Origin server (for the person who it is working for). You can check this by doing a `ping` on their device to your domain, and seeing if it resolves to your Origin IP. Or you can check the response headers for any with `CF-` prefix (which means it is likely routing through Cloudflare).
2. Another possibility is that your Origin server is blocking some Cloudflare servers but not others. For instance when you request the site, it may be routing through Cloudflare 'Server A', while when the other person requests your site, it is routing through 'Server B'. If 'Server A' requests are failing / being blocked, this would explain the behavior you are seeing. You can check your Origin server's access logs to see if this is occurring. If it is a blocking situation, you'll want to ensure all Cloudflare's IP are whitelisted - https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

More troubleshooting information from the Cloudflare forums - https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-522-connection-timed-out/42325

Comment: From all the possible solutions I've read, I think the problem is that aws elastic beanstalk is actually blocking some IP address of cloudflare in it's security groups. So any idea on how to whitelist all the IP addresses of cloudflare in the inbound settings of the security groups?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the setup required for Elastic Beanstalk security groups, sorry. I would say, that seems strange the default configuration would allow through some Cloudflare IP connections but not others. Seems more like some form of dynamic threat detection or rate limiting causing a false positive. But, those are just my blind guesses. Personally I'd recommend attempting to track down any logs you can find that will definitely show what is blocking the IP.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try that